# Django Admin Console giving 'str' object has no attribute '__iter__' error

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to make some changes in the fields using Djangos build in Admin console.It gives me  'str' object has no attribute '**iter**' error exception when i try to change some fields in the models.These fields are Foreign Keys

PROJECT MODEL CAUSES ERROR WHEN I CHANGE THE MANAGER FIELD

```
class Project(models.Model):
    """Project Model.
    """
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('Employee', blank=True, null=True)
    project = models.Manager()



class Employee(models.Model):
    """
    Employee Model.
    """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    projects = models.ManyToManyField('Project', blank=True)
    employee = models.Manager()
```

TRACEBACK

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  544.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  211.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1512.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  185.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1451.                 change_message = self.construct_change_message(request, form, formsets, add)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  185.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in construct_change_message
  942.         elif form.changed_data:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  35.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in changed_data
  447.             if field.has_changed(initial_value, data_value):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py" in has_changed
  1075.                 initial = field.to_python(initial)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py" in to_python
  424.         return super(DateField, self).to_python(value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py" in to_python
  395.             for format in self.input_formats:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __wrapper__
  112.                 return getattr(res, method_name)(*args, **kw)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/login/project/2/change/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute '__iter__'
```

admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *


admin.site.register(Employee)
admin.site.register(Project)
```

Comment: @e4c5 : Was this sarcasm?

I did not get what code do you want. I am using Django's default admin console

Comment: @e4c5 added the admin.py file in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem myself. I upgraded from Django 1.10 to 1.10.2 and that seems to have fixed it for me. Good luck.

Comment: Solve my problem too ;)